ReactNative Paper, extend compound component with forwardRef
I am using ReactNativePaper v4 and having a difficult time extending components with Typescript when using forwardRef and having a compoundcomponent: TextInput.Icon.  Here is my current setup:
const InputComponent = forwardRef<
  typeof RNPInput,
  Omit<TextInputProps, 'theme'>
>(({ label, style, ...rest }, ref) => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <View>
      {label && <Text>{label}</Text>}
      <RNPInput
        mode="outlined"
        outlineColor={theme.colors.backdrop}
        selectionColor={theme.colors.accent}
        style={style}
        // @ts-ignore
        ref={ref}
        theme={{ colors: { text: styles.input.color } }}
        {...rest}
      />
    </View>
  );
});

const TextInput = Object.assign(InputComponent, {
  Icon: RNPInput.Icon,
});

export { TextInput };

Then I consume like:
const Test = () => {
    return <TextInput  right={<TextInput.Icon name="eye"/>} />
}

The issues I have are:

the compound component props are not found, so name prop is not known.
if I remove the // @ts-ignore, the error is:


Type '(instance: (ComponentType<Pick<TextInputProps & RefAttributes & { mode?: "flat" | "outlined" | undefined; left?: ReactNode; right?: ReactNode; ... 18 more ...; theme: Theme; } & RefAttributes<...>, "label" | ... 123 more ... | "dense"> & { ...; }> & NonReactStatics<...>) | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'string'


If I remove the Omit<TextInputProps, 'theme'> form the component definition, when I consume the component, it has an error:


Property 'theme' is missing in type '{ right: Element; }' but required in type 'Omit<Props, "ref">'.

If I try to change the compound component definition to be more explicit, the Icon is not invoked
// Explicitly type the Icon component
const Icon = (props: TextInputIconProps) => (
  <RNPInput.Icon color="green" {...props} />
);

// Create the compound component
const TextInput = Object.assign(InputComponent, {
  Icon,
});


How can I correctly extend the TextInput from ReactNative paper so that: 1) forwardRef is correctly typed, and 2) Compound component is exported so that the props are known, and 3) remove the @ts-ignore?

forwardRef is being deprecated
https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef
You can just use ref instead
You can import like this
import {TextInput as TextInputReact} from 'react-native';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

Then use your ref like this
const ref = useRef<TextInputReact | null>(null);

Then use your react-native-paper TextInput with ref as usual
<TextInput ref={ref}

